# Javascript Mobile Swipe only works once

Tags: javascript, mobile, swipe

I've managed to put together some Javascript code to test mobile scrolling, the first instance of 'down' scrolling works fine, however I cant seem to scroll back up or scroll a second time.

I've tried searching for archived answers but couldnt locate anything, my code:

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

var xDown = null;                                                        
var yDown = null;                                                        

function handleTouchStart(evt) {                                         
xDown = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                      
yDown = evt.touches[0].clientY;                                      
};                                                

function handleTouchMove(evt) {

if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
    return;
}

var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
var yDiff = yDown - yUp;

if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
    if ( xDiff > 0 ) {

        /* left swipe */ 


    } else {
        /* right swipe */

    }                       
} else {
    if ( yDiff > 0 ) {

    var element = document.getElementById("background");
    element.classList.add("down-scroll").remove("up-scroll");


    } else { 
    var element = document.getElementById("background");
    element.classList.add("up-scroll").remove("down-scroll");           

    }                                                                 
}
/* reset values */
xDown = null;
yDown = null;  

};
```

Live example: http://peakwebdesigns.co.uk/work/greaves-sports/world-cup

Comment: `element.classList.add(`…`)` doesn’t return anything, so you can’t call `.remove` on it. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: Thank you for your help Xufox, ive now got it to swipe down + up, but it won't swipe down a second time, do I need to do some sort of check for what slide is active?   I'm using several background divs via css property: .background:nth-child(2) {
  background: white;
}

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create some functions to enable nextSlide and previousSlide to be called after checking the current slide:

```
// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ON MOBILE ------------- //

window.addEventListener('touchstart', handleTouchStart, false);        
window.addEventListener('touchmove', handleTouchMove, false);

var xDown = null;                                                        
var yDown = null;                                                        

function handleTouchStart(evt) {                                         
xDown = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                      
yDown = evt.touches[0].clientY;                                      
};                                                

function handleTouchMove(evt) {

// ------------- SLIDE MOTION ------------- //
function nextItem() {
currentSlideNumber++;
var $previousSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
$previousSlide.removeClass("up-scroll").addClass("down-scroll");
}

function previousItem() {
currentSlideNumber--;
var $currentSlide = $(".background").eq(currentSlideNumber);
$currentSlide.removeClass("down-scroll").addClass("up-scroll");
}

if ( ! xDown || ! yDown ) {
    return;
}

var xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;                                    
var yUp = evt.touches[0].clientY;

var xDiff = xDown - xUp;
var yDiff = yDown - yUp;

if ( Math.abs( xDiff ) > Math.abs( yDiff ) ) {/*most significant*/
    if ( xDiff > 0 ) {

        /* left swipe */ 


    } else {
        /* right swipe */

    }                       
} else {
    if ( yDiff > 0 ) {


   nextItem();


    } else { 

    previousItem();

    }                                                                 
}
/* reset values */
xDown = null;
yDown = null;  

};
```